# Is it not possible anymore to use chat:write:bot scope for Slack apps

Tags: slack-api

I want my app to `chat.postMessage`s to Slack, using the `icon_emoji` and `username` parameters so that I sometimes change the icon and name displayed.

From [the doc](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) of the method, it seems I have to set `as_user` to false. But when I do so, I'm getting a missing_scope error: I need scope chat:write:bot. (Same error whether I use my OAuth access token or my OAuth bot user access token)

But from [this page](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship) I got that they are disappearing? So are the parameters I want to use (icon_emoji and username) going to disappear as well?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, so I opened a support ticket with Slack and got "oh, this is probably a bug"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No, as of Dec 19 2019, you cannot use `icon_emoji`, etc

---

I ran into the same issue, and so I opened a support ticket with Slack. After a few messages back and forth, I got confirmation that this is likely a bug:

> With your help I was able to replicate the issue. I suspect this is a bug but I've escalated it to the Granular Bot Token team for a second opinion. As soon as I have more details I will let you know.

Edit:

I've received another update, which I've trimmed down to the essentials:

> When building the Granular Bot Token model our team really wanted to use this as an opportunity to slowly deprecate certain API behaviour. The as_user parameter is one of them. See the following comment from (https://api.slack.com/authentication/quickstart).
>
> > One effect worth noting: chat.postMessage and other chat.* methods no longer mess around with the as_user parameter. You're granted a single chat:write scope (no :user or :bot is appended). If you call the chat.postMessage method with your bot token, you post as the bot. If you've obtained a user token through the new install flow, and you call the method with your user token, you post as the user.
>
> So in regards to the action you are wanting to take, I'm afraid it's not possible with Granular Bot Token. We also recognized that the error this is throwing is completely unhelpful and confusing for developers. For this, we've created a bug to fix the error that's returned when Granular Bot tokens try to make restricted API calls.

I've requested clarification on whether it is just the `as_user` part that is deprecated, or the `icon_emoji` part as well.

Edit 2 (Dec 19, 2019 13:38 EST):

One, probably final, update:

> The option for app to change information such as username, avatar and icon via the API is up for debate as well. Currently with Granular Bot Tokens you can only update that information via your API management page.

Which is really unfortunate.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do you have a link to this ticket so I can follow up, or is it a private ticket?

Comment: it is private, unfortunately, but I will keep this updated when I know more.

Comment: Arg. Unfortunate indeed. Do you know if it's still possible to create legacy apps by any chance? I have not managed to do so.

Comment: I do not know, unfortunately. If there is, it's not obvious.

Comment: The [chat:write.customize](https://api.slack.com/scopes/chat:write.customize) app scope should appears to send messages as  with a customized username and avatar, and I have been using it, but as of October 11, 2020 it seems to have stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a Scope to "Bot Token Scopes" with the value of "chat:write.customize".

https://api.slack.com/scopes/chat:write.customize

then I had to re-install my app. And it worked like I expected.

Note: I tried this as it was a suggestion from a comment. but it worked so i am adding it as an answer.

Comment: This does not work for me.